# Boolean won't change even if the condition is met

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

The following method adds an object of type `Member` to an array:

```
public boolean addMember(Member m) {
    boolean result = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < members.length; i++){
            if(members[i] == null){


                members[i] = m;
                result = true;
            }
        }


    return result;
}
```

as you can see, I also return a boolean result if the current position was null. The problem is that, even though the condition is met - the object is added, it displays it no problem - the result boolean always stays false. Why? and how can I make it change?

Comment: Why are you using arrays and not a `List` or even a `Set` for this?

Comment: Seconded, use a list.

Comment: Also, the way you are doing it you won't add the element at the first empty position but fill up the whole array with it since you don't break out of your loop.

Comment: you need a `break` :-)

Comment: @m0skit0 I thought OP's problem was that it never returned true, i.e. the loop never ran/no nulls in the array oO

Comment: it might be useful if you can show the code how you instantiate and fill the `members` array

Comment: actually this code fills up the whole array with the same object, why i am using arrays is because, well, universities just love them, i don't understand why.

Comment: ^ They want you to learn and appreciate memory management. You will learn or have learned pointers very shortly.

Comment: n1234 if you wanna add your comment as a solution i'll mark it as correct, i can't believe how dumb i am right now, thanks people =)

Comment: `break` will work..., but why not return directly. No need for another variable...

Comment: @user2209644 true, it would have. How do you instantiate it?

Comment: the problem was that i never broke out of the loop when adding the object to the array, and i was foolishly checking only the first index of the array which gave me the confidence that there were no bugs in it, breaking after the addition to the array did the trick. If someone wants to add it as an answer i'll be more than glad to accept it, thank you all again

Comment: I did answer your question OP ^ ?

Comment: yes you did, accepted the answer, thank you good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `break`

```
public boolean addMember(Member m) {
    boolean result = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        if (members[i] == null) {
            members[i] = m;
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Or event better, no need for a flag:

```
public boolean addMember(Member m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        if (members[i] == null) {
            members[i] = m;
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @samoz No, it does change the logic indeed.

Comment: @samoz With this logic, no values of members are changed after the first null is found.

Comment: @samoz Sure, it fixes the "store it multiple times" bug. Nevertheless, this might not be the real cause of the described behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is probably being added. It probably wasn't null to begin with, so the loop never runs, which is why the boolean is false at completion.

Actually, this seems like the correct behavior, since if there is not a null space in the members array, the new element does not overwrite existing elements, so false is correct here.